# Calling WCF Service using Angular js

Tags: angularjs, wcf

I have created a sample web application using Angular Js. In this application i am calling some WCF Services. While Calling the WCF Service which i have deployed in my IIS i am getting the below error :

**Status : 404
StatusCode : Not Found**

Can anyone please help me. i am praticing how to use and manage Angular JS for CRUD operations.
Below is my Angular JS Code:

```
loginApp.factory("CS_Login", function ($http, $q, $log) {
    return {
        "Login": function (emailAddress, Password) {
            alert("inside Factory");
            var loginResponse = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: "http://localhost/EmployeeWCFService/EmployeeService.svc/LoginApp",
                method: "GET",
                params: { emailAddress: emailAddress, Password: Password }
            }).then(function (resp) {
                $log.log(resp);
                loginResponse.resolve(resp);
            },
            function (e_resp) {
                $log.error(e_resp);
                loginResponse.reject(e_resp);
            })
            return loginResponse.promise;
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: are you sure about your bindings? ..i mean http://localhost ..as no PORT?? like http://localhost:8080

Comment: Thanks Federico, yes URL is right, when i remove the /LoginApp i.e. just http://localhost/EmployeeWCFService/EmployeeService.svc we can see the service. And this service i have deployed in my local machine IIS.
Also i am using basicHttpBindings for this

Comment: mm i have never try woth WCF..but always with Asp.NET WEBAPI ... if you try to to the GET to your WCF with POSTMAN .. does it work?

Comment: Yes i tried with POST as well, but getting the same error message i.e. 404 not found

Comment: no .. i mean POSTMAN .. not with POST method!!!.. POSTMAN is a Rest client (to simulate rest calls)

Comment: Can you please update the above code and type here?

Comment: as far as I know there is a configuration in the `Web.confing` file but by default you should make request to address like this -> `http://localhost/EmployeeWCFService/EmployeeService.svc/rest/LoginApp` and `http://localhost/EmployeeWCFService/EmployeeService.svc/rest/help` should show you the methods of your webservice. So my opinion is that you miss **rest** from the request URL

Comment: Hmmm yes i think. Thanks for your reply federico. Will update my service to Rest